# Facebook SDK for Android and GCM jar mismatch and WakefulBroadcastReceiver unknown

Tags: java, android, facebook, jar

im working on a app where im integrating Facebook and GCM and the problem im facing is

```
The import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved
```

and i think i know the reason behind it, when i used Facebook SDK for Android a JAR mismatch error was shown then i removed the android-support-v4.jar from my project's lib folder and the problem was resolved now when i want to integrate GCM to my app the "WakefulBroadcastReceiver " is unknown which might be because i removed my projects JAR file.. but if i paste the JAR file again in my project's lib folder the Facebook SDK will show errors, i have also tried to remove JAR from facebook SDK's lib folder but it doesnt work...

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`jar` mismatch means you're having same `jar` file with different `signatures`, copy one of `jar` file and paste in other. So **`your project`** and **`Facebook SDK`** will have same `jar` with same `signature`. After that do clean build and let us know.